# Как добавить границу блока, а контент при этом не смещать с первоначального положения?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть 3 блока в сетке `bootstrap`, где в блок посередине обрамлен границей, но в таком виде текст в блоке смещается относительно первоначального положения, что можно наблюдать относительно соседей. Как правильно сохранить границу и в тоже время текст оставить при этом на месте. Пробовал делать `border` через псевдоклассы `:before` `:after` но у меня только 2 стороны закрываются вместо 4ех. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/jze8gqb1/378/)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

#col-border {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col">
      <p>1 of 3</p>
      <p>1 of 3</p>
      <p>1 of 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col-border">
      <p>2 of 3</p>
      <p>2 of 3</p>
      <p>2 of 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>3 of 3</p>
      <p>3 of 3</p>
      <p>3 of 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил

```
#col-border {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: а этот пример прям решил проблему, увеличил ширину и высоту блока в центре дополнительно на 5px и сократил ширины соседних, так как размер блока не ограничен box-sizing, тогда было проще добавить padding только в class col, эффект был бы тот же. Куда проще тогда вместо border использовать outline, тогда та же рамка просто выйдет за блок и не будет прессовать остальное

Answer (score -1):

пропиши в стиле box-sizing: border-box; и все будет норм

Comment: внимательно читайте задание и проблему в ней описанную